# How to find the index of the minimum value in a row?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm using Google spreadsheet and I need to get the column header for the minimum value of a row:

```
4       4       8
3       1       4
2       3       1
```

The first column stores max_score of a test for each question. The other rows store actual_score for each student. How can I get the header, for example 8, as the header for the column with the max value for the difference (max_score - actual_score) for each row?

Edit: I'm using the following range:

```
INDEX($D$1:$O$1,MATCH(MAX(4-D5,4-E5, 10-F5, 6-G5, 4-H5, 10-I5, 10-J5, 8-K5, 
10-L5, 4-M5, 8-N5, 12-O5), D5:O5, 0))
```

And I have numbers in cells D1:O1. MAX returns 8 and that's the value stored in N1, but the formula gives an error NO MATCH.

Comment: Pleas change the data example to reflect your actual need.

Comment: First column or first row has the max score.  Is the max score (4,4,8) or (4,3,2)?

Comment: It's  the row 4, 4, 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,LARGE(IF(MAX($A$1:$C$1-A2:C2)=$A$1:$C$1-A2:C2,COLUMN(A2:C2)),1))
```

In Excel this will require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting Edit mode.  Google sheets does not.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do I change to consider the MIN percentage actual_score/max_score instead of the difference?